# OOP query, showing 2 queries

Tags: php, sql, oop

I'm currently having trouble with inserting data into my database. I have this code to start inserting the query:

```
if (Input::exists()) {
    $validate = new Validate();
    $link = new Link();

    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'name'  =>  array(
            'related'   =>  'hyperlink'
        ),

        'hyperlink' =>  array(
            'related'   =>  'name'
        )
    ));

    if ($validation->passed()) {
        try {
            $link->create(array(
                'uid'       =>  $user->data()->id,
                'name'      =>  Input::get('name'),
                'hyperlink' =>  Input::get('hyperlink')
            ));
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        echo '<div class="error">';
        echo '<ol>';

        foreach ($validation->errors() as $error) {
            echo '<li>' . $error . '</li>';
        }

        echo '</div>';
        echo '</ol>';
    }
}
```

When running this code, the create method is called:

```
public function create($fields = array()) {
    if (!$this->_db->insert('user_links', $fields)) {
        echo 'Something went wrong';
    }
}
```

Now the script will run the insert method:

```
public function insert($table, $fields = array()) {
    if (count($fields)) {
        $value_list = implode(", ", array_values($fields));
        $keys = array_keys($fields);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `$table` (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES ({$value_list})";

        if (!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Everything goes fine, but then when it goes to the query() method, it appears there are 2 queries saved in it. I already heard about `__destruct`, so I'm wondering if it has anything to do with that.

Here's the query method:

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    $this->_error = false;
    echo $sql;

    if ($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;

        if (count($params)) {
            foreach ($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if ($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

When I echo the `$sql` in the query() method, it echo's this:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?INSERT INTO user_links (uid,name,hyperlink) VALUES (1, test, test)`

The `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?` comes from a get() method. But In the code where I set all data for my query, I'm not using any get() method. Unless to grab the values of the inputfields. (But that's not the problem)

Thanks for help!

**EDIT 1:**

Select method:

```
public function get($table, $where) {

    return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);

}
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
public function find($user = null) {

    if ($user) {

        $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'email';
        $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));

        if ($data->count()) {

        $this->_data = $data->first();

        return true;

        }

    }

}
```

**EDIT 3:**

```
public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {

    if (count($where) === 3) {

        $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=', '<>');

        $field      = $where[0];
        $operator   = $where[1];
        $value      = $where[2];

        if (in_array($operator, $operators)) {

            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

            if (!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {

                return $this;

            }

        }
    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: Assuming you're on laravel? Specify your framework

Comment: Plain php, no framework.

Comment: show you `select` or `get` method of `PDO Wrapper` class, I bet you must passed some other query along the way to get the current user

Comment: Am I missing something or are you not properly preparing your insert statement? It looks like you are putting the values directly into the insert string

Comment: Don't think so, I followed  a tutorial. That guy realy knows his stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not terminating you SQL statement. you need to put `;` at end of query string so that both query can run.

Like in `insert()` method

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 
         `$table` (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) 
         VALUES ({$value_list});"; //added semicolon
```

and in `get()` method which is calling `action` do the same

currently your sql is not valid because of two queries are merged, `;` will make both valid and it will work.

```
'uid'       =>  $user->data()->id,
```

above code is the cause of second query

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?
```

**Note :** You should consider a `singleton` to deal with db and should run one query at a time. currently your `$sql` property is having two queries concated `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?INSERT INTO user_links (uid,name,hyperlink) VALUES (1, test, test)`. or an array of query will also work.

**Update:**

add `;` in action method like this and try

```
$sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ? ;";
```

Comment: share you action `$this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);` method if above doesn't solved your issue

Comment: Edited the post again

Comment: share you `action` method used by `get()`

Comment: In the very first code block (top of page), I had mentioned `$user = new User();`. That caused the double query to appear. I deleted that, but my query is still not working :\

Comment: whats the `echo $sql;` now giving

Comment: After i deleted `$user = new User()`, my `echo $sql` is this: `INSERT INTO user_links (uid, name, hyperlink) VALUES (1, test, test)`

Comment: If i `var_dump($this);` and submit my form, it is showing everything from the users. Should I clear `$this` or something?